# Convert files on directories that are not always there

Tags: bash, recursion, converters

I've got a script that runs when a torrent download is finished to see if there are FLAC audio files and if yes convert them to MP3. Until today I've used:

```
for file in "$torrentpath"/"$torrentname"/*.flac
do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -qscale:a 0 "${file[@]/%flac/mp3}"

done
```

But I realised that when a torrent comes containing sub-directories the script is useless. I've tried messing around for the past few days with "find" and "if" and other ways but I can't really see the answer. I know it's there.

The script should just test if there are sub-dirs and execute ffmpeg on those, otherwise directly go with the conversion.

Any little hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to handle arbitrary subdirectories in bash:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in "$torrentpath/$torrentname"/**/*.flac
do ...
```

Comment: That is like.. gold, for me at least. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
find "$torrentpath"/"$torrentname" -name '*.flac' -print | while read file; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -qscale:a 0 "${file[@]/%flac/mp3}"
done
```

Comment: This solution is broken when filenames contain spaces. As a general rule, don't parse the output of `find` unless you take all the necessary precautions. You could rewrite this very nicely using the `-exec` command of `find`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, how would you handle manipulating the filename in `find -exec`?

Comment: @glennjackman e.g., `find "$torrentpath/$torrentname" -name '*.flac' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -qscale:a 0 "${1[@]/%flac/mp3}"' _ {} \;`. (ok, it's `-exec`+`bash` but very robust nonetheless and, moreover, could be faster than globs if the directory is huge, since globs are sorted).

Comment: but you have to spawn a bash process for every match, which will slow you down (probably not too noticably compared to ffmpeg's execution)

Comment: @glennjackman sure... then you could: `find "$torrentpath/$torrentname" -name '*.flac' -exec bash -c 'for i in "$@"; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -qscale:a 0 "${i[@]/%flac/mp3}"; done' _ {} +` and it turns out that this could be much faster than bash globs alone. Anyway, for me the solution you gave is the best one (and I upvoted it `;)`), especially here since there might not be that many files in each torrent.